# parse.com : how to set parse object pointer to null in android

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I have a `ParseObject` called `Quest` and it has a column named `Treasure` which is a pointer to another `ParseObject`.

I want to set `Treasure` to `null`. Tried searching for help and tried setting `quest. put("Treasure",JSONObject.NULL)` but it still gives me an error.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `quest.put("Treasure",null)`?

Comment: I see no problem in this and it works for me, can you post the error you are getting ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @inevitable21 don't put quest.put("Treasure" , null); it's automatic set in undefine variable.